# Iterate over JSON data and append field text to div (ES6)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am using the fetch:

```
  fetch('https://www.website.com/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    });
});
```

How can I use ES6 to grab my data field, and it's text content; and append to `<p id="paragraph"></p>`

Sample data/JSON response:

```
..'1yr_short_copy":"<p>Our 1 Year Money Back Guarantee either leaves you'..
```

*Essentially am looking for the best way to do it with fetch and ES6 (non-jQuery).*

*Desired output:*

```
<p id="paragraph">Our 1 Year Money Back Guarantee either leaves you....</p>
```

Comment: So what is in the JSON? It is unclear what is hard about reading the object.

Comment: Perhaps sharing a sample output would help. As epascarello notes, it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, and as such, not exactly clear what you're asking. What is your "data field", and where is `<p id="paragraph>`...? Is that in the response or on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is first parsed to an `object` in `response.json` and then you turn it back into JSON with `JSON.stringify(myJson)`, which makes it unusable. Dont' do that. Just use the `object` you've parsed to update the `textContent` value of the `<p id="paragraph">`.

Because your `1yr_short_copy` property starts with a number you can only select it by using *brackets* instead of the *dot* notation. Avoid naming the first character of the keys in your object with numbers.

```
fetch('https://www.website.com/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(obj) {
    const paragraph = document.getElementById('id');
    if (paragraph !== null && obj.hasOwnProperty('1yr_short_copy') { // Check if element is found and your 1yr_short_copy key exists.
       paragraph.textContent = obj['1yr_short_copy']; // Brackets notation
    }
  });
});
```